# Is there an Library to support NSDictionary travelling in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Background:
After parsing json data to NSDictionary or NSArray, the expression is extremely long when you want to reach a deep attribute or value. For example:

```
[[[book objectForKey:@"author"] objectForKey@"contact"] objectForKey:@"mobile"]
[[[[book objectForKey:@"author"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey"@"contact"] objectForKey:@"mobile"]
```

Is there a tool to facilitate this use a query expression like "/author/contact/mobile" or "/author/[0]/contact/mobile" and used as [SimpleTraveller getValueFromDic:book, @"/author/contact/mobile"]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
id obj = [book valueForKeyPath:@"author.contact.mobile"];
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I've read some document about key-value coding, and it seems it supports for array, but I can't figure it out how to use valueForKeyPath for NSArray.

Comment: It seems it allows only to access/set keys for all elements in array, not at arbitrary index. I'm not 100% sure though